# "Incorrect Plot" label in ggpairs

Tags: r, ggally

I have a simple question.

How can I get totally blank spaces in the upper panel of a matrix using ggpairs?

I am using this code:

```
ggpairs(iris, columns = 2:4, title = "[1989]",
        upper = list (continuous = "blanck"), lower = list(continuous = "points"), diag = list(continuous = "blanck"),
        axisLabels = "show",
        legends = TRUE)
```

I just want the 3 plots on the lower panel, but the code print grids and the label "Incorrect Plot" both in the diagonal and upper panel.

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Well you could type `blank` instead of `blanck` for starters :P (and it will be fixed)

Comment: It's good practice to specify the package you are using (in your case GGally, I assume).

Comment: If LyzandeR doesn't want to answer, you should compose your own answer and mark it as right so others can find it. Comments are considered ephemeral. Also otherwise it will be an eternally unanswered question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code would be:

```
ggpairs(iris, columns = 2:4, title = "[1989]",
    upper = list (continuous = "blank"), lower = list(continuous = "points"), diag = list(continuous = "blank"),
    axisLabels = "show",
    legends = TRUE)
```